# How to parse protobuf in python, byte data

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Hello I receive binary data with protobuf, I would like to decode this msg.

my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Server {
    oneof msg {
        Values values = 3;
        Ack ack = 5;
    }
    int64 ack_id = 8;
}

message Ack {
    int64 ack_id = 1;
    bool is_ok = 2;
    string error_msg = 3;
}

message Values {

    message Value {
        int64 timestamp = 1;
        int64 id = 2;
        oneof value {
            string string_value = 3;
            double double_value = 4;
            sint32 int_value = 5;
        }
    }

    repeated Value values = 1;
}
```

I compiled my proto file using protoc.

here is my example python code to decode this proto msg.

```
import server_pb2
values = server_pb2.Values.Value()

values.ParseFromString(data)
print(values.timestamp)
print(values.id)
print(values.value)
```

but always returned values are 0.

```
0
0
0.0
```

example byte data input:

`b'\x1a\x17\n\x15\x08\xc0\xd6\xb2\x9f\x06\x10\xaa\xed\xe3\xe4\n!\xe9\x0b!\xe7\xfd\xff\xef?@\x1a'`

bin ascii:
`1a170a1508c0d6b29f0610aaede3e40a21e90b21e7fdffef3f401a`

base64:
`GhcKFQjA1rKfBhCq7ePkCiHpCyHn/f/vP0Aa`

I don't know if these proto data are correct

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
import server_pb2


data = b'\x1a\x17\n\x15\x08\xc0\xd6\xb2\x9f\x06\x10\xaa\xed\xe3\xe4\n!\xe9\x0b!\xe7\xfd\xff\xef?@\x1a'

server = server_pb2.Server()
server.ParseFromString(data)
print(server)
```

Yields:

```
values {
  values {
    timestamp: 1676454720
    id: 2895705770
    double_value: 0.999999
  }
}
ack_id: 26
```

###### Update responding to comment

Continuing the above code:

```py
for value in server.values.values:
    print(value.timestamp)
    print(value.id)
    print(value.double_value)
```

Yields:

```
1676454720
2895705770
0.999999
```

The `proto` duplicates the field name `values`. `Server` has a field `values` of type `Values` and `Values` contains a field `values` of type `Value`. So the Python code has some redundancy:

```py
server_values = server.values
values_values = server.values.values # Or server_values.values
```

Comment: Thanks!
how to get access fields?

eg. id, timestamp etc.

Comment: You're welcome. I encourage you to read the [Python tutorial](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/). I'll update the answer with an example showing reading values.